# can we use layout in Customview?

Tags: android

friends,

i have a custom view class

```
public class Zoom extends View {
        private Drawable image;
        private int zoomControler=20; 
        public Zoom(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            image=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
            setFocusable(true);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            super.onDraw(canvas);

            //TransparentPanel tp = new TransparentPanel(this.getContext());

            //Button MyButton = new Button(this.getContext());
            //MyButton.setText("Press me");

            //tp.addView(MyButton);

            image.setBounds((getWidth()/2)-zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)-zoomControler, (getWidth()/2)+zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)+zoomControler);
            image.draw(canvas);




        }

}
```

can i use SetContentView(R.layout.mylayout) in this custom view  to display that design?

or

how can i display button with image ondraw method as i have commented the code ?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you will have to create a custom XML in the `res/layout` dir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<your.package.Zoom xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

As you want to use `R.layout.mylayout` the XML file will have to be called `mylayout.xml`